# jMeter - Blazemeter Correlation Recorder Plugin Template not available

Tags: jmeter, correlation, blazemeter

I'm new to jMeter and appreciate your help.

1. I'm using jMeter Version 5.5
2. I've installed the Plugin Manager as per these instructions https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager
3. I then re-started jMeter, opened Options > Plugins Manager
4. I went to "Available Plugins" and searched for "BlazeMeter - Correlation Recorder Plugin" and installed it
5. I restarted jMeter and accepted an upgrade to 4) afterward I re-started jMeter again
6. The plugin shows correctly in the Plugin Manager [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5vnv.png)
7. When I go to Files > Templates I can't select the Correlation Recorder Template [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBZrN.png)

As per the instruction below
https://q-automations.com/2020/11/07/auto-correlation-in-jmeter/
I should be able to see a template for the Correlation Recorder Template.

Can you help?
Thank you :)

I tried to re-start jMeter a few times. I also tried to uninstall and re-install the plugin a few times.

I was expecting a template to show as per those instructions
https://q-automations.com/2020/11/07/auto-correlation-in-jmeter/

Answer (score 0):

There is a scrollbar on the right hand of the templates, my expectation is that you need to scroll it down a little bit as the `bzm - Correlation Recorder` template should be somewhere at the bottom

[image]

Also it might be a better idea to stick to the documentation from the plugin's vendor:

- [Correlations Recorder Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CorrelationRecorder)
- [Introducing the JMeter Correlation Recorder Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-correlation-plugin-blazemeter)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned, that I did scroll to the bottom, but it's not there.

Comment: I think if you perform clean installation of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) followed by installation of the [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) followed by installation of the [Correlations Recording Plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CorrelationRecorder) you should see the template as well.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I followed those steps and installed everything from scratch and everything works fine, apart from the "template" part giving me not the option of the new correlation template. I might give up and create a template manually as I can't see what could cause it. I also tried to install the previous version of Apache jMeter 5.4.1, bu t exactly the same issue. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was resolved when I moved Jmeter to the other directory and removed read only access from the folder. As it is my work machine I guess I had some write rights restrictions which lead to the situation when template was not properly installed.
Note: running Jmeter as administrator before plugin installation didn't help me in my situation, but maybe can help in some other cases.